# Is there an alternative to printf?

Tags: c++, printf

`printf` can be accessed if you `#include <stdio.h>`. I like using `printf` because of the format specifiers, and it just feels nicer than doing `std::cout << "something\n";`.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib> // to use rand()

int main() {
    int randNum = rand()%10 + 1;
    printf("Hey, we got %d!\n", randNum);
    return 0;
}
```

vs

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> // to use rand()
using std::cout;

int main() {
    int randNum = rand()%10 + 1;
    cout << "Hey, we got " << randNum << "!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

But a user in a discord server that I am in said it was bad practice because "printf is unsafe, use std::cout".

A second user said it was bad because it's not type safe (the first user did mention type safety but not in depth).

The second user said,

> Typesafety is enforced by the compiler. However by using a variadic function, the compiler cannot tell the type of the arguments at runtime; it can't know them in advance. The function needs some way to tell what type of arguments to expect, and the `printf` family of C functions did this through the format string specifiers.

So I'm looking for other alternatives.

If there are none I guess I'll just stick to `std::cout`

Comment: Stream output (using derived classes of `std::stream`) is the common and recommended way to do output in C++. Formatting is possible using stream manipulators offered in `<iomanip>`. To deny it might result in fighting against wind mills... ;-)

Comment: Output formatting using `std::cout` can get quite a pain, though. QT's QString comes with a similar typesafe function. Well, I wouldn't introduce QT just for this purpose, but if you are using it anyway... You could, too, write your own `printf` function based on variadic templates. You'd leave out the specific type identifier then, though (d, u, x, ...).

Comment: Depending on the compiler you use, `printf` will be type safe in practice because many compilers can parse and check your format strings. My recommendation is to ignore iostreams; they're a mess.

Comment: Well, there's always `putc()` and `puts()` ... :)

Comment: You can generally include `<cstdio>` for the `stdio` header file in C++. While `iostream` is the general C++ workhorse, there are a number of instances where `stdio` functions can be a more efficient approach.

Comment: Yes, printf is unsafe. A Google search will bring up relevant results, e.g. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459630/how-can-a-format-string-vulnerability-be-exploited), which is why MS brought in a more secure replacement, [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/printf-s-printf-s-l-wprintf-s-wprintf-s-l?view=vs-2019). The proper replacement is iostreams. On the same subject C++11 brought with it a new template library for random numbers that does a much better job than C's rand, [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/)

Comment: @UriRaz Even the safe MS variants of printf family are variadic functions. Curious how MS would solve the main issue for being unsafe: How to assure that arguments passed to the function match the specifiers in the format string?

Comment: Also note that, in some [environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31882168/the-input-output-library-stdio-h-shall-not-be-used), you aren't even allowed to use `printf`. If you are looking for some alternatives, you might consider [{fmt}](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GNU C++ compiler `g++` checks `printf` arguments at compile-time. If you specify `-Wall` on the command line, it issues a warning if it detects a mismatch. So if you are using this compiler, you can use `printf` without worrying.

Your compiler may or may not offer a similar service. But hell, use `printf` anyway, at least in preference to the ridiculous `cout` mechanism. Or for a type-safe solution, you might consider using the [Boost Format library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/format/doc/format.html).

**Edited to add:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33321751/428857) has a discussion that you might find interesting.

Comment: Why not std::format?

Comment: @Sebastian: umm...because `std::format` wasn't available in June 2019, when I posted this answer. That is why I suggested its predecessor, the Boost Format library.

Comment: Okay, fair enough :-)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative on embedded devices you could consider the <1KB Open Source [Trice](https://github.com/rokath/trice), which allows printf-like comfort also inside interrupts by delegating the printing task to the external log viewer. I developed this tool, because I found nothing better.

Answer (score 0):

As kindly explained by @TonyK, `snprintf` and `sprintf` are used to write into a buffer and not to the standard stream. Instead of just answering the specific question, this explains a broader solution.

---

For a "safer" function, you could look at using `snprintf` where the size of the object is explicitly specified.

Without specifying the size and using `printf`, you have to "trust" that the provided `char*` is a valid C-string with terminating null character, otherwise `printf` will keep reading the memory.

---

Generally speaking, if the requirements is to only use C and only have a dependency on the associated C runtime library (glibc on Linux, msvcrt/ucrt on Windows, ...), using only C header and and using a C compiler makes sense.

If using C++ is an option, using `std::cout` is a natural choice as it will support displaying any object implementing the `ostream::operator<<`.

Answers on what is the best choice will dependent on what you try to achieve.

Comment: Don't you just love these downvoters who don't explain what's wrong with the answer, so helpful. (Btw, I assume it's because your answer doesn't address the core issue of OPs question (type safety of variadic arguments), and because printf and snprintf do very different things (one writes to standard out, the other writes into a char array)).

Comment: `printf` is just as safe as `snprintf`. The `snprintf` function is provided to guard against the buffer overrun errors that `sprintf` (not `printf`) is vulnerable to.

Comment: @Chipster: did you read my comment? Or did you just not believe it?

Comment: @TonyK Thanks for your help clarifying, I edited my original post to make things explicit.

Comment: @Chipster Thanks for your support. That said, while my post is informational, it doesn't explicitly answer the question asked.